# Error running xunit test with unquote library and Visual Studio 2015 - Method not found

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, f#, xunit

Getting this error "System.MissingMethodException : Method not found: 'Swensen.Unquote.UnquotedExpression Swensen.Unquote.Operators.unquote(Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.FSharpExpr)" in Visual Studio 2015.  Tried it in Visual Studio 2013 and it works.

Comment: Almost certainly you are using incompatible versions of some of your references.

Answer (score 11):

You'll need to add an assembly redirect to an app.config file associated with your unit test project. Something like this ought to do it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="FSharp.Core"
                          publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
                          culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.3.1.0"
                         newVersion="4.4.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```